# Excute Reader is not a memeber of query

Tags: vb.net, inline-code

i am using this line of code it give me message `Excute Reader is not a memeber of query`

```
Dim Query As MySqlCommand = New   MySqlCommand(SQL,System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager["Conncetion"].ConnectionStringSettings)
 Dim RS As MySqlDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader()
```

Here  i use the query in SQL is `SQL = "SELECT e.* FROM ipm_fuel.tbl_events e inner join ipm_website.tbl_lots l on e.lot_id=l.id`

Thanks for your comments

Comment: What is the `MySqlCommand` class ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin i call a function form MySql.Data because i am using mysql as for database i include reference of this

Comment: Ok, it could have been a custom class created by you for your project.  So, what version of the MySql Connector/NET are you using ? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: What is "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager["Conncetion"].ConnectionStringSettings"